# How to make a table with Iframe responsive

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, responsive-design

i have been reading some of the post releted Resposive Website on StackExchange. Also tried some codes on my localhost but non of them worked out for me.

Project :- i have made an Hotel Booking Engine with object oriented programming in php i have made a form useing table structure where user can select the check in check out dates and other details.

Problem - i try to make the form resposive but nothing is working for me

Objective :- To make form responsive where people can select the Check in Check Out Dates

**PHP Code**

```
$output .='<table cellspacing="2" border="0" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">';
            if(!empty($output_hotels)){
                $output .= '<tr><td><label>'._SELECT_HOTEL.':</label></td></tr>
                        <tr><td nowrap="nowrap">'.$output_hotels.'</td></tr>';                  
                $output .= '<tr><td><label>'._SELECT_LOCATION.':</label></td></tr>
                        <tr><td nowrap="nowrap">'.$output_locations.'</td></tr>';
            }           
            $output .= '<tr><td>'._CHECK_IN.': '.$output1.'</td>&nbsp;<tb>'._CHECK_OUT.':'.$output2.'</td>&nbsp;<td>'.$output3.'</td>;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            if(!empty($output_hotels)){
                $output .= '<tr><td style="height:5px"></td></tr>
                        <tr><td nowrap="nowrap">'.$output_sort_by.'</td></tr>';
            }
            $output .= '<input class="button" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(\'reservation-form\').submit()" value="'._CHECK_AVAILABILITY.'" /></table>';
```

**IFRAME Codes**

```
if(hsJsHost != ''){

    var hsJsKey = (typeof hsJsKey === 'undefined') ? '' : hsJsKey;
    var hsJsHost = (typeof hsJsHost === 'undefined') ? '' : hsJsHost;

    if(hsJsKey != '' && hsJsHost != ''){

        var encoded_host = encode64(hsJsHost);
        var encoded_key = encode64(hsJsKey);        

        var filePath = 'widgets/ipanel-left/index.php?host='+encoded_host+'&key='+encoded_key;

        // setup the iframe target
        var iframe='<iframe id="frame" name="widget" src="#" width="15px" height="200px" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>';
        // write the iframe to the page
        document.write(iframe);

        var myIframe = parent.document.getElementById("frame");
        // setup the width and height
        myIframe.height = 100;
        myIframe.width = 815;

        myIframe.src = hsJsHost+filePath;
        // set the style of the iframe
        myIframe.style.border = "1px solid #aaa";
        myIframe.style.padding = "8px";
        myIframe.style.margin-right = "10px";
    }

}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to learn the basics of responsive CSS. That means media queries, % and em/rem values etc. here are some basic resources

[Mozilla media query page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

[css units](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

You can't build much without this basic foundation.